# Django App for Academic Journal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I'm looking a Django app I'm looking for an app that that allows for management and integration of footnotes for articles

just wondering if anyone had seen something around...

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not a perfect fit, but I wrote a Django app that supports annotations and footnotes on texts, although the app concentrates more on annotations. If you have the time to read source and adapt it to your needs, [clone the app from GitHub](http://github.com/stefanw/django-annotatetext).